# How to use single requiredfield validator for two or three textboxes in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to use single requiredfield validator for two or three textboxes in asp.net ?

Comment: why?  Copy and paste is pretty easy these days...

Comment: copy and pasting complex regex's is far more complicated than applying DataAnnotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would definitely be to use [DataAnnotations](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/08/aspnet-webforms-validation-with-data.html) for reusable validation.